# Верное написание слова

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно написать: "заворожённо смотрел" или "заворожено смотрел"? В чем отличия? Встречала разные варианты: "Тинга заворожено смотрела на ежевечерний бешеный водоворот" (Владимир Скрипкин. Тинга. 2003); "Миша-молдаванин заворожённо смотрел на летающую по клетке соратницу..." (Виктор Астафьев. Обертон. 1995-1996).

Comment: 2003 год выпуска-просто опечатка, последнее время на корректоров деньги не тратят, не вычитывают ошибки, так что не следует грамотность проверять по печатным изданиям последних лет, это в советские времена вычитывали и вклеивали листок : "на стр...ошибка". А Ворд исправил,видимо, потому что евместоё написали, он не контролирует дифференцированные написания.

Comment: Спасибо, буду теперь знать по каким изданиям лучше проверять.

Answer (score 5):

Правильный вариант: заворожённо.

Это наречие со следующей схемой образования: заворожить - заворожённый  - заворожённо. Заворожённый - причастие, выбор НН можно определить по наличию приставки.

Сравнить: Она заворожена этим чудом природы. Здесь краткое причастие в роли сказуемого, одна буква Н.

Ударение проверено по словарю Резниченко. Также у Бунина: Лес, точно терем расписной,
Лиловый, золотой, багряный, Стоит над солнечной поляной,Заворожённый тишиной...

Comment: София, спасибо за помощь! У меня Office Word почему-то подчеркивает красным слово "заворожённо" и исправляет его на "заворожено".

Comment: Это  всё  из-за  зыбкости  правил  употребления  буквы  Ё.

Answer (score 1):

"Завороженный": стилистический оттенок -"влюблённый". "Заворожённый" - "заколдованный".

Comment: Приведите  примеры.

Comment: Постойте, выходит что есть два слова - заворожЕнный и заворожЁнный? Я думала что это одно слово, с одним ударением на Ё. Просто некоторые над "Ё" не ставят точек, вот и выглядит как "Е". Ну вроде "еж". А это два разных слова?